# .dex file exceed 64k when i added google maps api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, intellij-idea, android-multidex

I created a google maps activity in **Intellij Idea 2016.2.2**, but when i added my api key the `64k limit exceed` error occurred. i know that we have to enable `multidex true` in `build.gradle` but the issue is that my 'build.gradle' files looks like this:

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
   jcenter()
  } 
 dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

   // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
   // in the individual module build.gradle files }  } allprojects {repositories {
   jcenter()
  }  
}  
task clean(type: Delete) {  delete rootProject.buildDir }
```

(sorry for messed up alignment of code)

**1-** So as there is no **defaultConfig** here and when i tries to add it manually it gives me error.

**2-** And when i added this line in my manifest

```
"android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">"
```

again error.

I tried everything written here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html
and also in other questions people asked about this problem nothing worked. 
Anyone knows how to resolve the issue? I'll be thankful :)

Comment: Can you add the app level line where you added the google maps API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your project contains one module (that is `app`), you should have two `build.gradle` files:
[image: screenshot]

The first one is for your project (that is the one you are posting the snippet from), you should neither add dependencies there (as noted in the commented out line there), nor you should alter `defaultConfig` there.

The other one is for your `app` module. This is where you should add your dependencies, and set `multiDexEnabled true`. you should see `defaultConfig` block there.

Comment: Yes there was another build.gradle . For those who also cant find it here's the path > 'yourappname'/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to add only the part of Google Play Services that you need and not all of it in dependecies.
Like this:  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
This will make that you don't exceed the limit